# Invoke dynamic java method with out reflection

Tags: java

I have data type which contains 100 properties and 100 getter methods (getproperty1....getproperty100).

I get an input from the user like

```
Property1
Property2
.
.
Property100
```

How can I invoke in a quick way the method in this logic

```
For property1 I need to invoke getproperty1
For propertyI I need to invoke getpropertyI
```

How can I do this with out using `if else`, or `switch` statement or reflection in an efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: To how many data bundles are you applying a given list of properties?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably going to be an array or hashmap of some type, and access it by index/key:

```
public class DataType {
    private Map<String, DataProperty> data = new HashMap<String, DataProperty>();

    public DataProperty getProperty(String key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }

    public void setProperty(String key, DataProperty value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Although, 100 properties seems like a lot...  see if you should break it up or otherwise re-organize it.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** If you need to **invoke** multiple methods I would suggest using the [`Strategy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern. In it's simplest form you could try

```
public interface Command<T> {
    public T getProperty();
}
```

and then create as many implementations as necessary.

**2.** If you are only interested in the **return** type and not the actual invokation the `Map<String, T>` would be a better alternative.

**3.** If you want to pass around the information in your program a good alternative would be to use the `enum` approach

```
public enum Command {
   Property1("some value"),
   Property2("some other value");

   private String str;
   public Command(String str) {
       this.str = str;
   }

   public String getVal() {
       return str;
   }
}
```

Which can be used like

```
Command cmd = ...
String value = cmd.getVal();
```

Comment: How can strategy design pattern solve my problem ,it kinds of defining different implementation for abstract class.

Comment: @Blue Label, exactly, you declare `interface Foo { getProperty(); }` and supply one implementation for each property type. Although if you only need the return value the Map approach offered already would be better suited, or alternatively an `enum` approach.

Comment: Thanks but with enum approach I need to use switch statement and do it 100 times is that correct

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor the class to be a Map. If you have a large number of objects like that it seems more along the lines of a map than an object.

```
Map<String, Object>
```